# Subsetting rows by passing an argument to a function

Tags: r, subset

I have the following data frame which I imported into R using `read.table()` (I incorporated `read.table()` within `read_data()` which is a function I created that also throw messages in case the file name is not written appropriately):

```
> raw_data <- read_data("n44.txt")
[1] #### Reading txt file ####
> head(raw_data)
  subject block trial_num soa target_identity prime_type target_type congruency prime_exposure target_exposure button_pressed   rt ac
1      99     1         1 200              82          9           1          9              0              36              1 1253  1
2      99     1         2 102              95          2           1          2             75              36              1 1895  1
3      99     1         3  68             257          2           2          1             75              36              2 1049  1
4      99     1         4  68              62          9           1          9              0              36              1 1732  1
5      99     1         5  34             482          9           3          9              0              36              3  765  1
6      99     1         6  68              63          9           1          9              0              36              1 2027  1
```

Then I'm using  `raw_data` within the `early_prep()` function I created (I copied only the relevant part of the function):

```
early_prep <- function(file_name, keep_rows = NULL, id = NULL){

  if (is.null(id)) {
    # Stops running the function
    stop("~~~~~~~~~~~ id is missing. Please provide name of id column ~~~~~~~~~~~")
  }

  # Call read_data() function
  raw_data <- read_data(file_name)

  if (!is.null(keep_rows)) {
    raw_data <- raw_data[keep_rows, ]
    # Print to console
    print("#### Deleting unnecesarry rows in raw_data ####", quote = FALSE)

  }

  print(dim(raw_data))
  print(head(raw_data))
  return(raw_data)
  }

}
```

My problem is with `raw_data <- raw_data[keep_rows, ]`. 
When I enter `keep_rows = "raw_data$block > 1"` this is what I get:

```
> x1 <- early_prep(file_name = "n44.txt", keep_rows = "raw_data$block > 1", id = "subject")
[1] #### Reading txt file ####
[1] #### Deleting unnecesarry rows in raw_data ####
[1]  1 13
   subject block trial_num soa target_identity prime_type target_type congruency prime_exposure target_exposure button_pressed rt ac
NA      NA    NA        NA  NA              NA         NA          NA         NA             NA              NA             NA NA NA
```

How can I solve this so it will only delete the rows I want?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Best,

Ayala

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar. However because I use `read_data()` only inside `eraly_prep()` if I try what you suggested I get the following error: `Error in subset(raw_data, block > 1) : object 'raw_data' not found`. I want to use `read_data()` inside `early_prep()` and not as a stand alone function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the condition as a string and not as a real condition, so R can't evaluate it when you want it to.

if you still want to pass it as string you need to parse and eval it in the right place for example:

```
cond = eval(parse(text=keep_rows))
raw_data = raw_data[cond,]
```

This should work, I think